# How to build data streaming pipeline with python?

Tags: python, architecture, streaming

I want to build an application that analyzes tweets in real time and applies a machine-learning model.

What would be the best architecture to use that would allow easy integration of the python ecosystem? I've found a Faust from Robinhood, but it looks like it is no longer maintained.

Would really appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: You can get a  lot of articles on this topic with a google search. voting to close this question as this is opinion based

Comment: @sahasrara62 can't agree really, most tools I've found are paid tools, and apache Kafka which is a topic of most articles is not python native. Faust which allowed for easy integration with the python ecosystem is no longer maintained. If you could at least point me to the resources you've mentioned I would really appreciate it.

Comment: like for individual use, gattering tweets is troublesome and hetic process. dont know much on which is best tool out there which is free and open source, but you can ask here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python thisquestion, someone with much more experience will help you out for sure

Comment: Thank you @sahasrara62, I'll post a question in the channel.

Comment: FYI, `faust` is still maintained by the community and moved [here](https://github.com/faust-streaming/faust). It is sill the only framework I am aware of giving you the ability to have stateless AND stateful stream in python. A more mature framework (and actively maintained) is [Flink](https://flink.apache.org/) which begins to have a mature python API [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/python/overview/). Flink is harder to deploy and understand but seems more powerful and stable.